# Why does my mac report different free space on the internal SSD for different users?

Tags: macos, ssd

I've got a 2019 Macbook Pro 16" with a 1 TB internal SSD running MacOS Big Sur. I have three user accounts - one for me, and one each for two of my kids.

When I "Get Info" on the SSD,
User 1 shows 17 GB free.
User 2 shows 177 GB free.
User 3 shows 322 GB free.

What the heck is going on? Why is the number so different for all three uses?

Even when I launch disk utility, it sees that much free space for each user rather than showing the same amount of free space.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

[image: Get info for user 1]
[image: Get info for user 2]
[image: Get info for user 3]

Comment: What number shows in Disk Utility, and is it the same across all 3 users?

Comment: Disk utility shows the same number as the finder get info - and it's different for all three users.

Comment: There is some consistency. All three show about 981GB used and about 16GB unused (available minus purgeable) on the disk. It really is very full! The differences are how much can be purged by each user - that is disk which is in use, but can be returned if required. I am now guessing, but can imagine that would be mostly due to different cache usage - each user would only be able to purge their own cache.